# samsung galaxy note 3 factory reset

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, boot-loop

I have a samsung galaxy note 3. I tried to do a soft factory reset and my phone shut down and now it's been more than 15 minutes and my phone is flashing the samsung galaxy note logo then the little android guy laying with a red error on him and it goes back and forth. 
Is that normal? should it take long??

Comment: Sounds like you have a boot loop.  No, that's not normal.  It sounds like you should attempt doing another factory reset from Recovery, or you might end up having to flash the device.